# How to set firebase-database rule so users can read each other's data iff they share a group

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a chat-like realtime database with the following design

```
groups-
       |
       [groupId1]-
                 |
                 users-
                       |
                        [uid]
                        ....
       [groupId2]-
                 |
                 users-
                       |
                        [uid]
                        ....

users-
       |
       ....
       [uid]-
             |
             groups-
                   |
                   [groupId1]
                   [groupId2]
```

I want to set up Rules so user1 can ".read" data from users/user2 iff they share at least one group.
The data structure is such that i need every user can be in numerous groups so the users data must be under users/uid node and cannot be duplicated to every groups/[groupId]/users/[uid]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your question here with the Chat Example : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example

Comment: thanks for your answer. this example is indeed for chat, but does not include an answer to my problem. it does not include the scenario/design I described:  "user1 can ".read" data from users/user2 iff they share at least one group (or 'room')"